# My application only displays and filter data, is there a point of using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

All the application does is take a number of parameters specified by the end-user and calls a method inside a .dll made by another developer and displays it on a table. The application also has functions to filter such data.

Is there a point in using MVVM for such application? Because I can't seem to think of what to put in the Model and ViewModel.

Comment: This is perfect for MVVM. Your VM will be very basic. Your M is just all the data. The ummm V is just the umm View.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here; this is how I plan to structure the application. The Model will contain all the data returned by the .dll and it will contain all the methods that filters such data. The ViewModel will be ICommands for each filter and buttons on the View. The View will have one-way bindings to a set of data in the ViewModel.

Comment: Applications invariably seem to grow in size and scope over time. Investing in a good foundation in the beginning can make life easier down the road. If you are not already familiar with MVVM, a simple application would be the perfect place to try it out. So, yes :)

Answer (score 0):

It is highly debatable.
MVVM's main advantage is that it makes the code unit testable as it abstracts away from Visual Layer.
In your case, your data retreival is done by the dll method,so you need not have separate model/repositories/queries for retrieval.
Secondly, you are just displaying & filtering the data (locally), the simplest operation on Data.
MVVM is a great start even for small applications but weigh whether it is worth using,since you do not have complex UI,unit testing, CRUD operations.